# How can I use my verifyToken middleware in express router modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app like so:

```js
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');

app.use('/user', userRoutes);

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    // validate req.cookies.token
    next();
}
```

And I'm using an express router module like this:

```js
// routes/userRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:userid/data', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
    const data = await db.query()
    res.json(data)
   
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `verifyToken` is not accesible within the module. How can I use the same `verifyToken` middleware function throughout different express modules?

Comment: You can move verifyToken code to userRoutes.js file

Answer (score 1):

Move `verifyToken` to a different file and `export` it from there.

Then you can `import` it in other places.

One thing that you can do, that works well is to group all your authed routes under a common path and use `router.use` to make sure that you apply the `verifyToken` middleware on all of them.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is that just as simple as doing router.use(module.verifyToken)